# Python Regular Expression Data Search

Tags: python, regex, excel

I'm trying to parse through an excel file. There are certain "headers" (they are located inside cells) in this excel file that contain specific device names. Each of these names each contain an acronym surrounded by brackets. There are blank spaces in between each "header" with data for that device located between the two devices. However not all of the "headers" are located in the same column so I cant just scan down one hard coded column.

I want to be able to parse the excel file for the headers then scan the data for the device. Move onto the next device and repeat. I was thinking that using a regex that searched for brackets would be one viable way to do so. I usually struggle to come up with regular expressions if some could point me in the direction of a good example or could write one up that would be great. Also if anyone can think of a better way to parse this excel file would greatly appreciate it.

```
Header_A [HDA]
    data
    data
    data
    data
Header_B [HDB]
    data
    data
    data
    data
    Header_C [HDC]
        data
        data
        data
        data
```

Comment: So what's the expected output ?

Comment: I would like to have a list or dictionary that has Header_A and all of its data either as a key,value pair or all in one "cell" of the list

    [[Header_A [HDA],data,data,data,data],[Header_B,data,data,...],...]

Comment: Take a look at this. Offers possible workarounds to avoid parsing excel files: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/02/19.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, this might be overfitting your sample, but it does fit your sample:

(python 3)

```
sample= '''Header_A [HDA]
    data
    data
    data
    data
Header_B [HDB]
    data
    data
    data
    data
    Header_C [HDC]
        data
        data
        data
        data'''

lines=[{'raw':x} for x in sample.split('\n')]
largestIndent=0
for line in lines:
    line['indent']= (len(line['raw'])-len(line['raw'].lstrip()))//4
    line['content']= line['raw'].lstrip()
    if line['indent']>largestIndent:
        largestIndent=line['indent']
lines=[{'indent':-1, 'content':'', 'raw':''}] + lines

for depth in range(largestIndent,-1,-1):
    print ('depth={}'.format(depth))
    #print ('lines before ={}'.format(lines))
    children=[]
    for line in lines[::-1]:
        if line['indent']==depth:
            children=[line['content']]+children
        elif line['indent']==depth-1:
            if children !=[]:
                line['content']=[line['content']] + children
            children=[]
        else:
            pass
    #print ('lines after ={}'.format(lines))

outList=lines[0]['content'][1:]

print(outList)
```

Output:

```
[['Header_A [HDA]', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data'], ['Header_B [HDB]', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', ['Header_C [HDC]', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data']]]
```

No regex!

To my knowledge, regular expressions cannot possibly be made to intelligently parse arbitrarily nested text.

Comment: appreciate you taking the time out to write all that out but I would be scanning it from an excel file... from what I can tell yours is scanning from a text file?

Comment: @reddman: Mine just hard-coded the sample you provided with the question (as text). If you are actually going to parse the xls binary, I wouldn't know where to begin. See my comment on the question for a possible workaround.

Comment: @reddman - You may wish to consider using the [xlrd library](http://www.python-excel.org) library.